# Simulating an Empty Array Response from an HTTP Post Request using Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am using Karma to test my MEAN application, and am having difficulty returning an empty array from the $httpBackend 'expectPOST' method in AngularJS (ng-mock).

Here is the service method I am testing:

```
  this.getIds = function(path, callback) {
    // console.log('Sending request to get IDs to the path: ' + path);
    $http.post('/dropbox/getIds', {path: path} ).success(function(items) {
      if(items.error !== undefined) {
        console.log(items.error);
        callback('Error with Dropbox API files list request'); // Do not alter string
        return;
      }
      var empty = (items.length === 0) ? true : false;
      callback(items, empty);
    }).error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      callback('Error making ID request');
    });
  };
```

And here is the unit test code snippet:

```
it('should request Dropbox file IDs at a give path - no errors but empty response', function() {
  $httpBackend.expectPOST("/dropbox/getIds").respond({ data: [] });
  dropboxService.getIds('path', function(items, empty) {
    expect(items).to.deep.equal({data: []});
    expect(empty).to.deep.equal(true);
  });
});
```

The 'empty' variable should be true in this test as the HTTP POST response is an empty 'data' array, however the test fails as the 'empty' variable is actually false.

Can someone show me what I have done wrong, either in the test code or perhaps the service method itself?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

According to the Angular documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), the way you're handling the return of the callback is incorrect. In your test, items will be

```
{
  data: { data: [] } }
}
```

I think that your ternary should look like

```
var empty = (items.data.data.length === 0) ? true : false;
```

Then, you need to change your first assertion to

```
expect(items.data).to.deep.equal({data: []});
```

**Incorrect original post:**

You need to call for a digest on the scope for the promise to resolve. It should look something like this:

```
let scope;
beforeEach(() => {
  inject($rootScope => {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  });
});

it('should request Dropbox file IDs at a give path - no errors but empty response', function(done) {
  $httpBackend.expectPOST("/dropbox/getIds").respond({data: []});
  dropboxService.getIds('path', function(items, empty) {
    expect(items.data).to.deep.equal({data: []});
    expect(empty).to.deep.equal(true);
    done();
  });
  scope.$digest();
});
```

Comment: This does not work and does not address the issue. I have other tests that have callbacks and my tests work fine. The issue is simulating an empty array, not resolving the callback. I have other tests for this method where a complete array is returned and these work, if you require proof.